# Encryption / decryption using open ssl using C#

Tags: c#, openssl

i am using VS 2005 C# i want to encrypt and decrypt the complete file using OPEN SSL, can anyone help me in this regard.....

Answer (score 6):

OpenSSL Wrapper for .NET:
http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Just for clarification you can do encryption and decryption using libcrypto which is a part of OpenSSL. But it will be unnecessary and tedius to use OpenSSL library from C#.NET. As suggested by MiffTheFox, you should be able to do all cryptography stuff using System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: +1 for not forgetting about the crypto tools that come with OpenSSL

Answer (score 1):

Er... I think you misunderstand what OpenSSL is.

OpenSSL implements the [Secure Socket Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer) protocol for securely transporting data between a client and server via TCP/IP.

You should have a look at the classes offered by the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace, even [MSDN has a basic tutorial on encrypting files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010).

As per working on all platforms, I believe that most, if not all, of the System.Security.Cryptography namespace [works on Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Cryptography).

Comment: On the contrary, you misunderstand what OpenSSL is. It's more than just SSL and TLS. It also provides a full-strength general purpose cryptography library.

Answer (score -2):

SSL stands for Secure Socket Layer. It has nothing to do with encrypting files, but rather with secure (encrypted) TCP/IP connections. OpenSSL is an open source implementation, but you wouldn't need it on a Windows .NET platform.

Take a look at the *System.Security.Cryptography* namespace for implementations of some common cyphers that you can use to encrypt your file. AES (symmetric algorithm) and RSA (public key encryption) are both there and widely accepted.